# Spatie/Laravel Permission Views Templates

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

I have installed and configured the spatie permission, it is working is there any views or templates to work from Web, I mean if I create a user it should redirect a page where I can give the role and permission?

Comment: what do you mean by `work from Web`? please clarify your question

Comment: to assign the roles from WEB , Frontend or Page not to use commands

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't come with a boilerplate UI you need to make your own. Usually you could just extend the normal `register.blade.php`